# Deleting PostgreSQL completely? (ps aux | grep postgres showing results)

Tags: postgresql, command-line

I uninstalled the PostgreSQL app. 
I also un-installed the BigSQL using the uninstaller app it comes with.
I also deleted the "data" directory from `./PostgreSQL` directory after un-installation was done.

But still, whenever I do `ps aux | grep postgres showing results`, it gives me a result. I don't know why? What is that command actually supposed to do?

Comment: what does it show ?

Comment: the command above will always show itself as grep catch

Comment: add all the results after executing commands and also command you used for uninstallation . did you use   __--purge__ while uninstallation?